# How to run PHP code in Zend Studio 12?

Tags: php, configuration, xdebug, zend-studio, zend-debugger

I have installed Zend Studio 12.0.2 trial version in my linux operating system.How can I run php code in Zend Studio. I have search for the possible answers in stack overflow. I got this link http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/content/running_php_scripts_locally.htm but I cant find "php scripts" in run configurations.So I need to know what's the issue and how can I solve and run my php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server must be running the Zend Debugger or Xdebug in order for remote debugging and profiling capabilities to function. The Zend Debugger comes bundled with Zend Studio and Zend Server. For instructions on installing and configuring Xdebug, see [Installing Xdebug](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/content/installing_xdebug.htm) and [Configuring Xdebug](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/content/configuring_xdebug.htm).

You can read more in:

> http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/zend-studio.htm#running_php_web_pages.htm